# Different c++ classes where a member only differs by type

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

This is probably a really simple question, but I'm not sure what to search to find a solution. I have three classes as shown below:

```
class class_double_array {
public:
    double *value;
    int height;
    int width;

    void alloc(const int &h, const int &w);
}


class class_int_array {
public:
    int *value;
    int height;
    int width;

    void alloc(const int &h, const int &w);
}


class class_logical_array {
public:
    bool *value;
    int height;
    int width;

    void alloc(const int &h, const int &w);
}
```

where `alloc` would be:

```
void class_double_array::alloc(const int &h, const int &w) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
    value = (double*)calloc(h*w,sizeof(double));
}
```

Is there a standard way to organize these classes in c++? This is a pretty simplified example, but I have something similar where the class methods are basically the same but depend on the type of `value`. In this example, i'd have to rewrite `alloc` for each class even though its basically doing the same thing for each class. I was looking into using templates but I couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

Comment: A class template perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
template<typename T>
class T_array
{
public:
    T *value;
    int width;
    int height;

    void alloc(const int &h, const int &w)
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        value = (T*)calloc(h*w, sizeof(T));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, this is what I was looking for. When I searched templates, I only read about templates applied to functions. Should have read a little deeper. I'll accept in a few mins when I'm allowed to.